# How to process C++ file to remove ifdef'd out code

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have inherited a piece of C++ code which has many `#ifdef` branches to adjust the behaviour depending on the platform (`#ifdef __WIN32`, `#ifdef __APPLE__`, etc.). The code is unreadable in its current form because these preprocessor directives are nested, occur in the middle of functions and even in the middle of multi-line statements.

I'm looking for a way of somehow specifying some preprocessor tags and getting out a copy of the code as if the code had been pre-processed with those flags. I'd like the #include directives to be left untouched, though.
Example:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __APPLE__
std::cout << "This is Apple!" << std::endl;
#elif __WIN32
std::cout << "This is Windows" << std::endl;
#endif
```

would turn into:

```
#include <iostream>

std::cout << "This is Apple!" << std::endl;
```

after being processed by: `tool_i_want example.cpp __APPLE__`.

I've hacked a quick script that does something similar, but I'd like to know of better tested and more thorough tools. I am running a Linux distribution.

I have decided against just running the C-preprocessor because if I'm not mistaken it will expand the header files, which would make everything more unreadable.

Comment: You could just run the C pre-processor... (but it ends up being less readable than you might expect)

Comment: Asking for tools is offtopic here but [here you go](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unifdef).

Comment: Most compilers (all?) support running the preprocessor only. E.g. with Visual C++ that's option `/E` (plus options `/EP` and `/P`, check them out). I guess with g++ that's option `-E` then. Just check your compiler's documentation.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you very much, just tested it and worked like a charm. Would you mind making it an answer with the example usage so that I can accept it?

@Cheersandhth.-Alf I considered that, but doesn't it replace all `#include <library.h>` with the contents of `library.h`? That would make it too unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Complementing  [Basile Starynkevitch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40483482/2891462)'s answer, I want to mention [`coan`](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/). The major advantage is that, when used with `-m` it does not require the user to unset all symbols they want undefined.

This code:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __ANDROID__
std::cout << "In Android" << std::endl;
#endif

#ifndef __WIN32
std::cout << "Not a Windows platform" << std::endl;
#endif

#ifdef __APPLE__
std::cout << "In an Apple platform" << std::endl;
#elif __linux__
std::cout << "In a Linux platform" << std::endl;
#endif
```

would result in this code if simply run as: `unifdef -D__APPLE__ example.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef __ANDROID__
std::cout << "In Android" << std::endl;
#endif

#ifndef __WIN32
std::cout << "Not a Windows platform" << std::endl;
#endif

std::cout << "In an Apple platform" << std::endl;
```

Using `unifdef` one would need to use

`unifdef -D__APPLE__ -U__ANDROID__ -U__WIN32 -U__linux__ example.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

std::cout << "Not a Windows platform" << std::endl;

std::cout << "In an Apple platform" << std::endl;
```

This can get exhausting quickly when dealing with code considering several different platforms. With `coan` it's a matter of:

`coan source -D__APPLE__ -m example.cpp`.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`unifdef`](http://dotat.at/prog/unifdef/). It is designed for that purpose.